# Create, Write, Edit JSON file in Android Studio

Tags: java, android, json, file, android-studio

I would like to create a JSON file in the internal storage of the phone, to store data.
I want to be able to add objects ("configX") to the file and then read the data.

It should look something like this:

```
{

  "config1": {

    "component1": "url",
    "component2": "url",
    "component3": "url"

  },

  "config2": {

    "component1": "url",
    "component2": "url",
    "component3": "url"

  }

}
```

I can create a JSON file like this :

```
public void saveToJson(){
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject();
    try {
        json.put("component1", "url");
        json.put("component2", "url");

        String jsonString = json.toString();
        
        FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("jsonfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
        fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
        fos.close();

        Log.d("JSON" , json.toString());

    } catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

But how to put the components in the config object ? And how to retrieve the data ?

**EDIT 1 :**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/62474912/11652860

Thanks for the very detailed answer, I'm doing something wrong. I have an Activity where I put and save data to the json file:

```
public class Data {

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;

        public Data() {

        }

        public Data(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

    }
```

```
Map<String, String> config1 = new HashMap<>();
config1.put("component1", "url1");
config1.put("component2", "url1");
config1.put("component3", "url1");

Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
map.put("config1", config1);

Data data = new Data(map);

Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);

FileOutputStream fos = null;
 try {
fos = webViewActivity.this.openFileOutput("jsonfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
} catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
 try {
 fos.write(json.getBytes());
} catch (IOException e) {
  e.printStackTrace();
}
 try {
 fos.close();
} catch (IOException e) {
 e.printStackTrace();
}
```

And a fragment where I load the data :

```
public class Data {

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;

        public Data() {

        }

        public Data(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

    }
```

```
 public void load(){
        FileInputStream fis = null;

        try {

            fis = getContext().openFileInput("jsonfile.txt");
            InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);

            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String text;

            while ((text = br.readLine()) != null){
                sb.append(text).append("\n");

                Gson gson = new Gson();

                String json = gson.toJson(text);
                Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);

                String url = data.getMap().get("config1").get("component1");

                frameTV.setText(url);

            }


        } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        } finally {
            if (fis != null){
                try {
                    fis.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

The saving and loading parts must be wrong, but they worked for getting text out a text file

**EDIT 2 :**

I found the problem, I wasn't loading and saving properly :

SAVING:

```
String filename = "jsonfile.txt";

FileOutputStream outputStream;

try {
   outputStream = openFileOutput(filename, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
   outputStream.write(json.getBytes());
   outputStream.close();
} catch (Exception e) {
   e.printStackTrace();
}
```

LOADING :

```
FileInputStream fis = getContext().openFileInput("jsonfile.txt");
InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(fis);
BufferedReader bufferedReader = new BufferedReader(isr);
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
String line;
while ((line = bufferedReader.readLine()) != null) {
    sb.append(line);
}

String json = sb.toString();

Gson gson = new Gson();
Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
String priceURL = data.getMap().get("config1").get("url1");
```

**EDIT 3 :**

My problem now is that I need to create the file once and then check if the file exists, if it does I need to check if config1 exists if it doesn't I need to put config in the file.

But I can't check if config1 exists because I get : `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Map com.a.app.ui.app.appFragment$Data.getMap()`

I check if it exists by doing :

```
Boolean configTest = data.getMap().containsKey("config1");
if(!configTest){}
```

How can I create the file and check the data without getting a NullPointerException ?

Thank you for helping me !

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Google's Gson library will be helpful in this case.

1. Add dependency for Google Gson in your radle file.

```
    dependencies {
      implementation 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.8.6'
    }
```

2. Create a class for your data container

```
    public class Data {

        private Map<String, Map<String, String>> map;

        public Data() {
        }

        public Data(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }

        public Map<String, Map<String, String>> getMap() {
            return map;
        }

        public void setMap(Map<String, Map<String, String>> map) {
            this.map = map;
        }
    }
```

3. Add data to your class

```
    Map<String, String> config1 = new HashMap<>();
    config1.put("component1", "url1");
    config1.put("component2", "url1");
    config1.put("component3", "url1");

    Map<String, String> config2 = new HashMap<>();
    config2.put("component1", "url1");
    config2.put("component2", "url1");
    config2.put("component3", "url1");

    Map<String, Map<String, String>> map = new HashMap<>();
    map.put("config1", config1);
    map.put("config2", config2);

    Data data = new Data(map);
```

4. Get gson from data class

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(data);
```

5. You can now save this json in a file in a text format.
6. Now when reading, load the content of the text file in a String say 'jsonString'.
7. Deserialize the jsonString to Java Object

```
Data data = gson.fromJson(json, Data.class);
```

8. Access configurations

```
String url = data.getMap().get("config1").get("component1");
```

9. Add new configurations

```
    Map<String, String> config3 = new HashMap<>();
    config3.put("component1", "url1");
    config3.put("component2", "url1");
    config3.put("component3", "url1");

    data.getMap().put("config3", config3);
```

10. Follow again these steps to save configs
11. Or You can manually edit the text file to add configs according to the predefined format.

```
    {
       "maps":{
          "config2":{
             "component1":"url1",
             "component2":"url1",
             "component3":"url1"
          },
          "config1":{
             "component1":"url1",
             "component2":"url1",
             "component3":"url1"
          }
       }
    }
```

Comment: The only thing is that I can't add component 4,5,6  because they replace the components 1,2,3 : `map.put("config1", config1);` is the problem how can I solve this ?

Comment: If you want to add more components in the config1, after loading data class simply do data.getMap().get("config1").put("component4", "url4"); and resave the file. Just a reminder, you can also manually add components by editing the json file and adding another key value pair in the config1

Comment: For some reason when I run the code on an other emulator I get this error : `jsonfile.txt: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)` It looks like it isn't creating the text file but when I try creating it it still doesnt work, I get `java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.util.Map com.a.app.ui.app.appFragment$Data.getMap()' on a null object reference`

Comment: This is possibly because when changing devices the json file does not exist first. If you create an empty file the deserialization will fail causing a null pointer exception because it simply can't create the object from empty file. You need to initialize the object manually at least one time then save it. If your configuration file is need not to be changed everytime you change device, you can simply put the file in your assets folder this allows the file to be packed with the apk.

Comment: Thank you, I solved the problem with : `File file = getContext().getFileStreamPath(FILE_NAME);` then `if(!file.exists()){}` and if the file doesn't exist I create config1 (like you showed me) and put it in `map` and then creating and saving the file.

Answer (score 1):

Please consider using https://github.com/google/gson. You will be working with class instance rather than with JSONObject. Much more convenient.

Just to give you the idea of what you can do:

```
public class TestClass {
    private final Map<String, String> config1;
    private final Map<String, String> config2;

    public TestClass(Map<String, String> config1, Map<String, String> config2) {
        this.config1 = config1;
        this.config2 = config2;
    }
}
```

```
        Gson gson = new GsonBuilder().setPrettyPrinting().create();

        Map<String, String> config1 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        config1.put("hello1.1", "world1.1");
        config1.put("hello1.2", "world1.2");

        Map<String, String> config2 = new HashMap<String, String>();
        config2.put("hello2.1", "world2.1");
        config2.put("hello2.2", "world2.2");

        TestClass testClass = new TestClass(config1, config2);

        Log.d("zzz", gson.toJson(testClass));
```

The above prints:

```
    {
      "config1": {
        "hello1.1": "world1.1",
        "hello1.2": "world1.2"
      },
      "config2": {
        "hello2.1": "world2.1",
        "hello2.2": "world2.2"
      }
    }
```

You can go back and force between json string and the entity itself. To edit, you only need to work with object - natural and convenient way.

Answer (score 1):

This is how you create multiple Objects in a single JSON object:

```
//Creating first Object
JSONObject config1 = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("component1", "url");
    json.put("component2", "url");
    json.put("component2", "url");
    }
catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

//Creating second object
JSONObject config2 = new JSONObject();
try {
    json.put("component1", "url");
    json.put("component2", "url");
    json.put("component2", "url");
    }
catch (JSONException e) {
// TODO Auto-generated catch block
e.printStackTrace();
}

JSONObject finalJSON = new JSONObject();
try {
    //Adding both objects in one single object
    json.put("config1", config1);
    json.put("config2", config2);

    String jsonString = finalJSON.toString();

    FileOutputStream fos = this.openFileOutput("jsonfile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    fos.write(jsonString.getBytes());
    fos.close();

    Log.d("JSON" , json.toString());

} catch (IOException | JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

This will give you the desired output. Also, if in case you want to make any object an array, you can use `JSONArray` for that.

Answer (score 0):

```
**Edit JSON file in android programmatically**

sample JSON file (data.json):

    {
    "name": "John Smith",
    "age": 35,
    "city": "New York"
}

In your Android activity, read the contents of the JSON file using the following code:

    InputStream is = getAssets().open("data.json");
int size = is.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
is.read(buffer);
is.close();
String json = new String(buffer, "UTF-8");

  Parse the JSON data using the following code:
JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(json);
```

Edit the JSON data as needed. For example, you can change the value of the "age" field to 40 using the following code:

```
obj.put("age", 40);
```

Convert the modified JSONObject back to a JSON string using the following code:

```
String updatedJson = obj.toString();
```

Write the updated JSON data back to the file using the following code:

```
OutputStreamWriter outputStreamWriter = new OutputStreamWriter(openFileOutput("data.json", Context.MODE_PRIVATE));
```

outputStreamWriter.write(updatedJson);
outputStreamWriter.close();